# Unable to install R Studio

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, r

I tried to install `RStudio` after installing `R` in Ubuntu. When I clicked to install via `Ubuntu software`, clicking the install button does nothing. But sometimes when I click it, it starts loading and after a while it says `rstudio installed`. But it's not really installed.

So I installed it via terminal using:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-0.99.902-i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package rstudio.
(Reading database ... 175645 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-0.99.902-i386.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (0.99.902) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio:
 rstudio depends on libjpeg62; however:
  Package libjpeg62 is not installed.
 rstudio depends on libgstreamer0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer0.10-0 is not installed.
 rstudio depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rstudio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio
```

What are the steps to rectify this error?

Comment: The inability to install a `.deb` package through the 16.04 Software Center is a well known bug. My answer fixes your `dpkg` issue.

Comment: Answer provided here: http://askubuntu.com/a/882053/313415 helped me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Installing from a `.deb` file through `dpkg` does not resolve dependency issues the same way installation through `apt` will. After running the `sudo dpkg -i yourpackage.deb`, you should run `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix and complete the installation if any errors were encountered by `dpkg`.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to use `gdebi` to do RStudio installations. It automatically resolves dependencies (unlike `dpkg`).

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi rstudio-0.99.902-i386.deb
```

In fact, that's what RStudio themselves recommends for [rstudio-server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) installation.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

Add the following entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

All the mirrors are listed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/):

You can find out your corresponding Ubuntu release by doing this on command line

```
lsb_release -a
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i downloaded the dependency from the link below

https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb.html

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After downloading the zipped file use

```
sudo dpkg -i libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
```

to install the deb file to solve the dependency issues.

After that try and install R studio with

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-xenial-1.1.379-amd64.deb
```

and this should solve the problem. This should solve the problem and even if your software installer on ubuntu is not working.

Please and in case you see any other dependencies that you need to download just download it and use the above procedure and it should work. 
hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it worked when I've installed the follow dependencies:

libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.deb

All from https://packages.ubuntu.com/