# Issue with dependency of R Studio installation in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dependencies, r, rstudio

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.136-amd64.deb(Lendo banco de dados ... 213133
ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar rstudio-1.0.136-amd64.deb ...
A descompactar rstudio (1.0.136) sobre (1.0.136) ...
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de rstudio:
rstudio depende de libjpeg62; porém:
Pacote libjpeg62 não está instalado.
rstudio depende de libgstreamer0.10-0; porém:
Pacote libgstreamer0.10-0 não está instalado.
rstudio depende de libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0; porém:
Pacote libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 não está instalado.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote rstudio (--install):
problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
A processar 'triggers' para shared-mime-info (1.7-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para bamfdaemon (0.5.3+16.10.20160929-0ubuntu1)
...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
A processar 'triggers' para gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu4) ...
A processar 'triggers' para desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu1) ...
A processar 'triggers' para mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de: rstudio
```

I've already tried the gdebi solution but unfortunately it didn't work. When I run

```
sudo gdebi rstudio-1.0.136-amd64.deb
```

it appears:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgstreamer0.10-0
```

If you are wondering I also already did de install -f, autoclean, autoremove,etc procedures... But all of them let me here as well.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 13):

1. First download and install [libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer0.10-0/download)
2. Then download and install [libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/download)
3. Then try installing R-Studio

Comment: Same answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229529/2641825) Download libgstreamer0.10 packages from debian and install them.

Answer (score 3):

RStudio has a new preview out that doesn't require libgstreamer0.1 (it uses the new libgstreamer1.0 in Ubuntu 16). You can try it here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

This will become the stable build in the next few weeks.

Comment: Make sure to download the deb with `xenial` in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the Ubuntu 16.10 and tried to install RStudio with the exact same error messages. The `sudo apt-get -f install` does not work either.

I ended up installing an archived version of RStudio, version 0.98.1103 seems to work.
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio

Comment: I realized there are still dependency issues once installed. Here is the real way to get it done (as implied below). https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-16-10/