# My RStudio Application suddenly do not working, kindly look into it

Tags: software-installation, rstudio

```
englianhu@Scibrokes-Trading:~$ sudo gdebi rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

RStudio
 RStudio is a set of integrated tools designed to help you be more productive with R. It includes a console, syntax-highlighting editor that supports direct code execution, as well as tools for plotting, history, and workspace management.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:Y
/usr/bin/gdebi:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()
Selecting previously unselected package rstudio.
(Reading database ... 566539 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.4.1106) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio:
 rstudio depends on libclang-dev; however:
  Package libclang-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rstudio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio
```

and then

```
englianhu@Scibrokes-Trading:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libclang1-11 libobjc-10-dev libpq5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  rstudio
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 828 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

- [Unable to install R Studio [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784935/unable-to-install-r-studio)
- [How to automatically fetch missing dependencies when installing software from .deb? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58202/how-to-automatically-fetch-missing-dependencies-when-installing-software-from-d)
- [Installation of RStudio impossible in Ubuntu 19.04 - Dependency issue](https://community.rstudio.com/t/installation-of-rstudio-impossible-in-ubuntu-19-04-dependency-issue/33812/6)
- [broken dependencies in Ubuntu 16.04 Package libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64 is not configured yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979891/broken-dependencies-in-ubuntu-16-04-package-libgstreamer0-10-0amd64-is-not-conf)

Comment: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` suddenly doesn't work, kindly look into it.

[Preview 1.2.747 doesn't install in Ubuntu 16.04](https://community.rstudio.com/t/preview-1-2-747-doesnt-install-in-ubuntu-16-04/10005)

Comment: You must be careful to check whether a downloaded `.deb` package is suited for your distribution. If not, then you risk breaking your package management system. If you want to play it safe, only install software from the Ubuntu software sources.

Comment: Please [edit] your queston to provide details of how you attempted to install and to which version of ubuntu.

Comment: `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb`
and then
`sudo gdebi rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb` and appear above error, I installed and used RStudio on Linux since few days ago and working fine, https://community.rstudio.com/t/preview-1-2-747-doesnt-install-in-ubuntu-16-04/10005/11?u=englianhu useful few days ago but now not workable, kindly assist

Comment: It seems that your repositories are wrong. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy r-base-dev libc6 libc6-i386`. Also post full output of `sudo apt update` and `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` (if long use pastebin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that time using `Ubuntu 18.04LTS` with KDE plasma (might probably compatible issue), but now using `Kubuntu 20.04LST`, installed...

```
# update indices
apt update -qq

# install two helper packages we need
apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr

# import the signing key (by Michael Rutter) for these repo
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

# add the R 4.0 repo from CRAN -- adjust 'focal' to 'groovy' or 'bionic' as needed
add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
```

source :https://cloud.r-project.org/

```r
:~$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
:~$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
```

source : [RStudio v1.4.1717-3 Preview - Release Notes](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)

Answer (score 0):

At first I would recommend to install all updates to the system, remove packages marked for automatic removal using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Then install the R package by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall r-base-dev
```

Then you should know that RStudio provides correctly build deb-package for supported Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver), you can install it with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
```

Comment: `englianhu@Scibrokes-Trading:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-latest-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rstudio' instead of './rstudio-latest-amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:`

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.32-0ubuntu3) but 2.32-0ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`